# How To Parse JSON From Doubly Nested Response

Tags: json, crystal-lang

If I am getting a JSON response for a `cars` endpoint:

```
{
  data: {
    cars: [
      { make: "Tesla", model: "S" }
    ]
  }
}
```

And I have a class `Car`:

```
class Car
  JSON.mapping(
    make: String,
    model: String
  )
end
```

How can I parse the response so that the root goes down two levels? I know that I can do `Car.from_json(json_string, "data")`, but cannot find a way to specify another root key.

If there is no way to do this, what would be the simplest way without creating another class just for the `cars` level?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's several approaches you can take here.

One simple, albeit least efficient, is to just parse twice:

```
cars = Array(Car).from_json(JSON.parse(json)["data"]["cars"].to_json)
```

https://carc.in/#/r/6vnk

Then as you mentioned, you can just create mappings for the outer classes. There's no real faster way compared to what you have:

```
class Root
  JSON.mapping(data: Data)
end

class Data
  JSON.mapping(cars: Array(Car))
end

class Car
  JSON.mapping(
    make: String,
    model: String
  )
end

cars = Root.from_json(json).data.cars
```

https://carc.in/#/r/6vnm

Or if you prefer using the `JSON::Serializable` API:

```
class Root
  include JSON::Serializable
  property data : Data
end

class Data
  include JSON::Serializable
  property cars : Array(Car)
end

class Car
  include JSON::Serializable
  property  make : String
  property  model : String
end

cars = Root.from_json(json).data.cars
```

https://carc.in/#/r/6vno

Finally, a last approach is to drive the `JSON::PullParser` API directly:

```
parser = JSON::PullParser.new(json)
cars = nil
parser.on_key("data") do
  parser.on_key("cars") do
    cars = Array(Car).new(parser)
  end
end
```

https://carc.in/#/r/6vni

Comment: Thank you for this. I was hoping there was something more like `Array(Car).from_json(json.body, "data", "cars")`, but it seems this is the best available.

Comment: It's not too hard to implement something like this on your own. See a sketch here: https://carc.in/#/r/6wz2
But I don't think an API like this will ever be simple enough to understand and flexible enough at the same time to be  included into the stdlib.